# Multiple $http.get requests w/each JSON file split by h1 in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, json

I'm building my first Angular app using $http.get to pull raw json files from github and the output from each json file is split between headers in the HTML. The code I have is working but is very redundant and I was hoping that it could be refactored.

My controller looks like this:

```
.controller('mycontroller', function($scope, $http) {
  var firstUrl ='https://raw.githubusercontent.com/user/repo/master/first.json';
  var secondUrl ='https://raw.githubusercontent.com/user/repo/master/second.json';
  var thirdUrl ='https://raw.githubusercontent.com/user/repo/master/third.json';
  var fourthUrl ='https://raw.githubusercontent.com/user/repo/master/fourth.json';
  var fifthUrl ='https://raw.githubusercontent.com/user/repo/master/fifth.json';
  var sixthUrl ='https://raw.githubusercontent.com/user/repo/master/sixth.json';

  $http.get(firstUrl).success(function(data) {
      $scope.firsts = data;
  });

  $http.get(secondUrl).success(function(data) {
      $scope.seconds = data;
  });

  $http.get(thirdUrl).success(function(data) {
      $scope.thirds = data;
  });

  $http.get(fourthUrl).success(function(data) {
    $scope.fourths = data;
  });

  $http.get(fifthUrl).success(function(data) {
    $scope.fifths = data;
  });

  $http.get(sixthUrl).success(function(data) {
    $scope.sixths = data;
  });
});
```

My HTML looks like this:

```
 <div ng-controller="mycontroller" id="content" class="container">
          <br/>
          <div ng-repeat="first in firsts" class="panel panel-default">
              <h1 id="first">first</h1>
              <div class="panel-heading">
                  <h1><a href="{{first.url}}">{{first.company}}</a></h1>
                  <p>{{first.address}}</p>
              </div>
                <div class="list-group">
              <a ng-repeat="position in first.positions" class="list-group-item" href="{{first.url}}">
                  {{position.title}}
              </a>
          </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div ng-controller="mycontroller" id="content" class="container">
          <h1 id="second">second</h1>
          <hr/>
          <div ng-repeat="second in seconds" class="panel panel-default">
              <div class="panel-heading">
                  <h1><a href="{{second.url}}">{{second.company}}</a></h1>
                  <p>{{second.address}}</p>
              </div>
          <div class="list-group">
              <a ng-repeat="position in second.positions" class="list-group-item" href="{{second.url}}">
                  {{position.title}}
              </a>
          </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div ng-controller="mycontroller" id="content" class="container">
          <h1 id="thirds">third</h1>
          <hr/>
          <div ng-repeat="third in thirds" class="panel panel-default">
              <div class="panel-heading">
                  <h1><a href="{{third.url}}">{{third.company}}</a></h1>
                  <p>{{third.address}}</p>
              </div>
          <div class="list-group">
              <a ng-repeat="position in third.positions" class="list-group-item" href="{{third.url}}">
                  {{position.title}}
              </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div ng-controller="mycontroller" id="content" class="container">
          <h1 id="fourth">fourth</h1>
          <hr/>
          <div ng-repeat="fourth in fourths" class="panel panel-default">
              <div class="panel-heading">
                  <h1><a href="{{fourth.url}}">{{fourth.company}}</a></h1>
                  <p>{{fourth.address}}</p>
              </div>
          <div class="list-group">
              <a ng-repeat="position in fourth.positions" class="list-group-item" href="{{fourth.url}}">
                  {{position.title}}
              </a>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
      <div ng-controller="mycontroller" id="content" class="container">
          <h1 id="fifth">fifth</h1>
          <hr/>
          <div ng-repeat="fifth in fifths" class="panel panel-default">
              <div class="panel-heading">
                  <h1><a href="{{fifth.url}}">{{fifth.company}}</a></h1>
                  <p>{{fifth.address}}</p>
              </div>
          <div class="list-group">
              <a ng-repeat="position in fifth.positions" class="list-group-item" href="{{fifth.url}}">
                  {{position.title}}
              </a>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
      <div ng-controller="mycontroller" id="content" class="container">
          <h1 id="sixth">sixth</h1>
          <hr/>
          <div ng-repeat="sixth in fifths" class="panel panel-default">
              <div class="panel-heading">
                  <h1><a href="{{sixth.url}}">{{fifth.company}}</a></h1>
                  <p>{{sixth.address}}</p>
              </div>
          <div class="list-group">
              <a ng-repeat="position in sixth.positions" class="list-group-item" href="{{fifth.url}}">
                  {{position.title}}
              </a>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use arrays:

```
.controller('mycontroller', function($scope, $http, $q) {
    var urls = [
        'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/user/repo/master/first.json',
        'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/user/repo/master/second.json',
        'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/user/repo/master/third.json',
        'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/user/repo/master/fourth.json',
        'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/user/repo/master/fifth.json',
        'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/user/repo/master/sixth.json'
    ];

    var promises = urls.map(function(url) {
        return $http.get(url);
    });

    $q.all(promises).then(function(data) {
        // data will represent an array containing the response from all
        // AJAX requests
        $scope.data = data;
    });
});
```

and in your markup loop over the `data` array:

```
<div ng-controller="mycontroller" ng-repeat="elements in data" class="container">
    <h1>{{$index}}</h1>
    <hr/>
    <div ng-repeat="item in elements" class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h1><a href="{{item.url}}">{{item.company}}</a></h1>
            <p>{{item.address}}</p>
        </div>
        <div class="list-group">
            <a ng-repeat="position in item.positions" class="list-group-item" href="{{item.url}}">
                {{position.title}}
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: we have almost identical controller code =) but i still think controllers should be as thin as possible and breaking markup to reusable pieces (directives) and composing index.html from those pieces it much better.

Comment: I like the approach. The only issue is that `$q.all` is **not fail resilient**. If any of the `$http.get`s fail, the whole list will fail to display. It would be nice to populate the `data` array as each promise gets fulfilled so that the user could see partial results.

Answer (score 0):

you can chain your requests the one after the other , so they are executed after the previous one is complete.

snippet:

```
$http.get(url[0])
then(function(result){
     //get url[0] results 

     //make url[1] request
     return $http.get(url[1])
})
.then(function(result){
    //get url[1] results

    //make url[2] request
    return $http.get(url[2])
})
.then(function(result){
    //get url[2] results

    //make url[3] request
    return $http.get(url[3])
})
```

and so on. Now you get sure the each request to the server is going to execute after the previous one is complete.

Comment: But why wait for one request to complete in order to start the next one? Executing them in parallel would provide better user experience because the results will be shown much sooner.

Comment: You need to make sure that one request is complete before the next one start for one main reason, like(and trust me on large apps this happens) :
1. you may need data to return from the first request in order to use them on the next request and so on. On that case You dont want your next request start before the previous finish.

Comment: I agree that if you needed data from the first request in order to make the second then you should make them sequential. But this doesn't seem to be the case at all in this particular scenario. The OP has 6 different urls that can be requested independently.

Comment: Ok, there is no point on that but  , 
First of all how do you know that they are independent ?  and second it still  is a very structured solution (not mandatory) for the server requests to be in chain. 
Anyway, my personal opinion that comes from my personal experience, my friend, that's all, and aybody here can judge and evaluate.

Comment: I know that the requests are independent by looking at the OP. I can see 6 GET Ajax requests to 6 different urls and none of the requests depends on any state received from the previous one. You could perfectly fine execute those 6 requests in parallel without depending on any state. But I get your point - if the requests were inter-dependent  then they should have been executed sequentially - it's just that this is not the case with this example.

Answer (score 0):

The best approach is to break logic to independent pieces and implement functionality in directives. So let's create one:

```
 (function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('test-app', [])
        .controller('mainController', function ($scope) {
            $scope.sourceUrls = [
                'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/user/repo/master/first.json',
                'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/user/repo/master/second.json',
                'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/user/repo/master/third.json',
                'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/user/repo/master/fourth.json',
                'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/user/repo/master/fifth.json',
                'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/user/repo/master/sixth.json'
            ];
        })
        .directive('sourceViewer', function ($http) {
            return {
                restrict: 'E',
                templateUrl: 'your template url', //DO NOT FORGET TO PROVIDE PATH TO YOUR TEMPLATE HERE
                scope: {
                    url: '='
                },
                link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
                    $http.get(scope.url).success(function (data) {
                        $scope.model = data.data;
                    });
                }
            };
        });
  })();
```

And your directive template should be like this (provide path to html file containing this markup to your directive's `templateUrl` property):

```
<h1>{{url}}</h1>
<div>
    <p>{{model.address}}</p>
</div>
```

And then you use this controller in your index.html file is like:

```
<div ng-controller="main-controller">
  <source-viewer ng-repeat="sourceUrl in sourceUrls" url="sourceUrl"></div>
</div>
```